# Does Visual Studio 2015 Express for Web support SQL Server Compact?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-ce

I am currently working with a web application and would like to use SQL Server Compact as the DB containing the data. I have not been able to find a version of SQL Server Compact that I can use with Visual Studio. When I check the tools available to me I cannot find SQL Server Compact in the list of components even though it shows it was installed in the nuget packages. I have tried multiple versions with no luck so far. Is it possible to use this software with this version of VS 2015 Web Express.

```
Here's the log: 9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - -------------------------------------------
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Initializing Install...
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Extension Details...
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Identifier         : 41521019-e4c7-480c-8ea8-fc4a2c6f50aa
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Name               : SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Author             : ErikEJ
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version            : 4.5.0.2
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Description        : SQL Server Compact/SQLite Toolbox add-in for Visual Studio. This add-in adds several features to help your embedded database development efforts: Scripting of tables and data, import from SQL Server and CSV files and much, much more.
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Locale             : en-US
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - MoreInfoURL        : http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - InstalledByMSI     : False
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - SupportedFrameworkVersionRange : [4.0,4.9]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - 
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - SignatureState     : Unsigned
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Supported Products : 
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version : [10.0]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version : [11.0]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version : [12.0]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version : [14.0]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version : [15.0]
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - 
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - References         : 
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - -------------------------------------------------------
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Identifier   : Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Name         : Visual Studio MPF
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Version      : [10.0,)
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - MoreInfoURL  : 
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM - Nested       : No
9/2/2016 10:19:03 AM -
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  [Here's a walkthrough.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg606540(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to get into a database from a legacy application. Consider Googling "sql compact edition management studio" and the like. Add the specific version of SQL Compact (i.e. 3.5, 4) to your query.

Comment: I am trying to use this tool instead of the more traditional DBs due to security reasons at work. I have tried to install multiple times with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered by the creator of the tool ErikEJ within the "Q and A" section of the site: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0e313dfd-be80-4afb-b5e9-6e74d369f7a1/view/Reviews/2

His answer = "No extensions, including this one, work with VS Express, you need Community edition (free) or higher (Pro/Enterprise)"

Thanks for your responses.